# How to find and count the points that are elements of $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:x^2+y^2\le16 \wedge |y|\gt x\}$?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, regions

I am given the following set:

$\qquad \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\le16 \wedge |y|\gt x\}$

I want find and count the number of points in this set that have integer coordinates.

I drew this to help me visualize the problem.

[image: Plot]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Plot[{y /. Solve[x^2 + y^2 == 16, y], x, -x}, {x, -5, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Solid, Dashed, Dashed}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  GridLines -> {{-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}}]
```

I want to mark all of those points which are inside the set red as well as count them.

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just solve it:

```
sol = Solve[x^2 + y^2 <= 16 && Abs[y] > x, {x, y}, Integers];
```

Get how many:

```
Length@sol
```

Make the points (set point size or use `Disk` if you want bigger):

```
gr = Graphics[{Red, Point[{x, y}] /. sol}];
```

Then show them together:

```
Show[{Plot[{y /. Solve[x^2 + y^2 == 16, y], x, -x}, {x, -5, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Solid, Dashed, Dashed}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
   GridLines -> {{-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 
      1, 2, 3, 4}}], gr}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to do it.

```
grid = Catenate @ CoordinateBoundsArray[{{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}];
belongsQ[{x_, y_}] := x^2 + y^2 <= 16 && Abs[y] > x
pts = Pick[grid, belongsQ /@ grid];
Length[pts]
```

> `34`

```
Plot[{y /. Solve[x^2 + y^2 == 16, y], x, -x}, {x, -5, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed, Dashed},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}},
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
  PlotLegends -> False, 
  GridLines -> {{-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}},
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pts]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Was `Epilog` intended to do only things like this ?

Comment: @AHB. It is certainly much used to do things like this, but I would not say "only".

Answer (score 3):

```
plot1 = Plot[{y /. Solve[x^2 + y^2 == 16, y], x, -x}, {x, -5, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed, Dashed}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  GridLines -> {{-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 
     1, 2, 3, 4}}]
```

This shot works:

```
pts = {x, y} /. FindInstance[x^2 + y^2 <= 16 && Abs[y] > x, {x, y}, Integers, 100]
 (* 100 was chosen big enough to have all points found *)

plot2 = ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]}];

Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image: just to pass the 6 char limit]

```
Length@pts
```

> 34